# react error boundry and deferred calculation

Tags: reactjs

In this situation:

```
const A = () => (
  <B 
    calc={() => {throw Error('error!')}
  />
);

const B = ({calc}) => (
  <ErrorBoundry>
    <div>result: {calc()}</div>
  </ErrorBoundry>
);
```

(assuming that ErrorBoundry is the classic, simple ErrorBoundry form the react docs)
I see that the error is not caught by the error boundry. If I put the error boundry in `A`:

```
const A = () => (
  <ErrorBoundry>
    <B 
      calc={() => {throw Error('error!')}
    />
  </ErrorBoundry>
);

const B = ({calc}) => (
  <div>result: {calc()}</div>
);
```

It will be caught in A.
This is a bit confusing to me since the calculation is actually run on B's rendering, not A's.
so I fail to understand why having the ErrorBoundry in `B` won't catch the error.

Comment: In the first example, `ErrorBoundry` is a child of `B` and the error happens in `B`. So you're expecting a child component to catch an error in the parent.

Comment: @BrianThompson you mean "and the error happens in `A`" right? (not in `B`)

Comment: No, I mean `B`. The error happens as soon as `calc` is called : `<div>result: {calc()}</div>`. Even though the `div` would end up being a child of `ErrorBoundary`, the `calc` function is called during rendering of `B`, meaning the error happens in `B` (not covered by `ErrorBoundary`).

Comment: Whereas in example 2, the error still happens in the rendering of `B`, but `B` is a child of `ErrorBoundary`, so it is caught.

Comment: The `div` would be rendered inside the error boundary, yes. But `calc` is not called from the `div` it is called from `B` in order to provide the child text to `div`. Does that make sense? I think the confusion is coming from the difference of where things are rendered vs where they are evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify whats happening here, component A2 will catch the error while A won't.

The reason why A won't catch an error (the first situation in your case) because, like mentioned [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries), **Error boundaries** are React components that catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child **component** tree.

A `div` is not considered a [component](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#components).

```
const calc = () => {
  throw Error("error!");
};

const A = () => (
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <div>result: {calc()}</div>;
  </ErrorBoundary>
);

const A2 = () => (
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <B calc={calc} />
  </ErrorBoundary>
);

const B = ({ calc }) => <div>result: {calc()}</div>;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* <A /> */}
      <A2 />
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Error Boundary]

Comment: I think that brian thompson's comment above explain it - it's not a matter of div or react component but a matter of where the error code runs. If it runs in the same component where the ErrorBoundary is - it won't catch. But if the error is thrown in a deeper level - it will catch.

Comment: Saying "If it runs in the same component where the ErrorBoundary is - it won't catch. But if the error is thrown in a deeper level - it will catch." is exactly what this answer trying to explain.